# How to program different outputs for a .txt file string

Tags: c++

I seem to be having a problem with my current program.

What I am trying to do is create a program that outputs the possible decryptions of a stream of text found in a `.txt` file.

I have created my program up to the following point, but I have run into a problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream inputFile;

    string message = " ";
    int lengthOfMessage, counter = 0;
    int ord = 0;
    char newChar;
    inputFile.open("Jumbled Message.txt");

    if(!inputFile){
        cout<<"Input File Cannot Be Found"<<endl;
    }

    while(inputFile)
        getline(inputFile, message);                   
        lengthOfMessage = message.length();

        for(int i=0; i < lengthOfMessage; i++){

            ord = int(message[i]);
            ord += 1;
            newChar = char(ord);

        cout<<"Run"<<counter<<" unjumbled: "<<newChar<<endl;
        message= " ";
        counter ++; 
    }
}
```

Basically, when the program runs, each individual ASCII value of the text shift once is displayed beside each run amount.

For Example:

```
Run 0 Unjumbled: \
Run 1 Unjumbled: 2
Run 2 Unjumbled: x
```

As I have mentioned earlier, I am trying to create different possible message outputs for each run within the program.

Comment: `newChar = char(ord);` - why, oh, why?? Memory leaks aside, `operator<<` is overloaded for `char const*` to expect a null terminator, i.e. no other than `ord` = `0` is valid. Also, declare variables at the point and scope you need them. Listing (nearly) all variables at the top of the function is unprofessional...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to convert the full string before displaying it. Then got onto the next line in the file.

Here I have made a sample that convert a line in the file to all possible values and display them, then repeat for next line until end of file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream         inputFile;
  std::string           jumbled_message;
  std::string           unjumbled_message;
  int                   line = 0;

  inputFile.open("Jumbled Messages.txt");
  if (!inputFile)
  {
      std::cerr << "Input File Cannot Be Found" << std::endl;
      return 1;
  }

  while (inputFile)
  {
      getline(inputFile, jumbled_message);
      unjumbled_message.resize(jumbled_message.size());
      for (int shift = 0; shift < 255; shift++)
      {
          for(size_t i = 0; i < jumbled_message.size(); i++)
          {
              unjumbled_message[i] = jumbled_message[i] + shift;
          }
          std::cout<< "Line" << line << " - shift: " << shift
                   << " - unjumbled: "<< unjumbled_message
                   << std::endl;
      }
      unjumbled_message.clear();
      line++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```